# ErrorCurlException: 7: Failed to connect to 255.255.255.255: Network is unreachable

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting this error in my PHP code:

```
ErrorCurlException: 7: Failed to connect to 255.255.255.255: Network is unreachable
```

Here is my code:

```
require_once 'src/facebook.php'; //include the facebook php sdk
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '*************',    //app id
    'secret' => '**********************', // app secret
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) { // check if current user is authenticated
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');  //get current user's profile information using open graph
        $email = $user_profile['email'];
        echo"<script>alert(\"$name\");</script>";
    } catch(Exception $e)    {
        $name="Error".$e;
    }
}
echo"<script>alert(\"$name\");</script>";
?>
```

The same code is working on a different page. I am just a beginner and don't know much about FB API.

Comment: Is `255.255.255.255` the ip address of the error message? If so, something on your client or network is blocking facebook.

Comment: `255.255.255.255` is a broadcast IP; not something you would want to use for connecting to Facebook's APIs. Do you set that IP address somewhere? If not then you should contact your network administrator. It may have something to do with a firewall, or some similar security measure.

Comment: I get the same error on a shared hosting. They blocked facebook calls.